# Finding XML element from RESTClient with XMLSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, httpbuilder

I'm writing a Spock test, in which I have a REST web service that returns an XML like this:

```
<templates>
 <userTemplate id="1109">
  <settingsXml/>
  <type>USER</type>
  <label>template111</label>
  <description>template111</description>
 </userTemplate>
 <userTemplate id="1141" isAutomaticTemplate="true">
     <settingsXml/>
  <type>USER</type>
  <label>An updated user template</label>
 </userTemplate>
</templates>
```

My test want to verify that a particular userTemplate it is **not** in this document. So, using HTTP Builder's REST client and XMLSlurper, I'm doing the following:

```
   res = settingsService.get(path: "templates")
   res.status == 200
   def delTemplate = res.data.userTemplate.find {
    println it.@id == newUserTemplateId
    it.@id == newUserTemplateId
   }
   delTemplate
```

I would have thought that *delTemplate* would be null after calling **find** (because there's no template with that id; the expresion println it.@id == newUserTemplateId always prints *false*, in this case the value of *newUserTemplateId* is 1171).
However, *delTemplate* is of type groovy.util.slurpersupport.NoChildren, and it seems to contain a userTemplate element.

Funny thing is if I write a quick script with the same XML as text (as oppossed of reading it from REST), `res.userTemplate.find { it.@id == 1171 }` returns null as expected.

What am I doing wrong, or how could I solve this?

Comment: So does your service return an XMLSlurper object?

Comment: It does, as far as I know. RESTClient returns an http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseDecorator.htm, with the response data already parsed into an XMLSlurper object.   


I have fixed this issue now, by using findAll() and then checking for isEmpty(), but I'm still curious why it doesnt't work with find() and checking for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use httpBuilder with XMLSlurper for JUnit testing of rest webservices. There is a gotcha that find() on a GPathResult always returns another GPathResult - but that this might contain no children.

For your particular usecase, the idiom I'd use would be:

```
def resp = settingsService.get(path: 'templates')
assert resp.success
assert resp.data.userTemplate.find {it.@id == newUserTemplateId}.isEmpty()
```